# Generate rownumber based on table result from an sp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So assume I have a stored procedure which has a parameter based on which columns are ordered and returned as a table.

I would like to insert to a new table same output but with a rownumber, in the same order which stored procedure returns values.

```
create table test
(
    ColA    varchar(50),
    ColB    varchar(50)
);

GO
INSERT INTO test(ColA,ColB)
VALUES('aaa','zzz'),('yyy','bbb');
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc
(
    @OrderCol VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM test
    ORDER BY CASE @OrderCol WHEN 'A' THEN ColA WHEN 'B' THEN ColB END
END
GO

create table testRn
(
    RowNum  int,
    ColA    varchar(50),
    ColB    varchar(50)
);
GO
```

So as you can see there is a param is an SP @OrderCol and result is returned from an sp in ordered format, I just want to insert to a table with the same row number, **but I can't use @OrderCol or alter a stored procedure**.

Aka, I want to run this:

```
INSERT INTO testRn(RowNum,ColA,ColB)
EXEC TestProc @OrderCol = 'B'
```

And `testRn.RowNum` there becomes this:

[image]

Maybe I should create a temporary table with an identity field, insert it there, and then use Identity field as a row number?

Comment: Can you rely on knowing the logic that dictates the ordering inside the stored procedure? Or do you need to treat it like a secret box that could change at any time?

Comment: I can rely on it, whatver is passed there table is returned in correct order

Answer (score 0):

In *two steps* you can `INSERT` your stored procedure data into `testRn`, then `UPDATE` `testRn` with a incremental row number using a user-defined variable:

```
INSERT INTO testRn(ColA,ColB)
EXEC TestProc @OrderCol = 'B';
```

```
DECLARE @id INT 
SET @id = 0 
UPDATE testRn
SET @id = RowNum = @id + 1;
```

**Result:**

```
| RowNum | ColA | ColB  |
|--------|------|-------|
| 1      | yyy  | bbb   |
| 2      | aaa  | zzz   |
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/vUYiZlqA).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that

```
declare @testRn table(RowNum int identity(1,1),  ColA varchar(50), ColB  varchar(50))

insert into @testRn
EXEC TestProc @OrderCol = 'A'

select * from @testRn

-- final table
insert testRn select * from testRn
```

if you need persist the result then some id should be saved with the result set, maybe some internal counter or uniqueidentifier

Comment: Oh I don't know if you can guarantee those identity values will always be assigned in the order of output